# Grouped bar graphs with numerical values in python

Tags: python, graph, seaborn, data-visualization

I cannot share my dataset but it looks something like this.

| category | sales | profit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| (7 types) | (float) | (float) |

There are actually 6 columns with numerical variables. I want to plot this on python as a grouped bar graph with category as the x axis and individual bar lines for the average of the numerical columns. The hue argument in seaborn's catplot only takes in categorical values so I can't use that.

Is there any other method to plot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seaborn prefers its data in ["long form"](http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data).  You can use [`df.melt(id_vars='category')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) to convert the dataframe.

Here is an example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

sns.set()
df = pd.DataFrame({'category': np.random.choice([*'abcdefg'], 100),
                   'sales': np.random.randint(1000, 2000, 100),
                   'profit': np.random.randint(100, 200, 100)})
long_df = df.melt(id_vars='category')
sns.barplot(data=long_df, x='category', y='value', hue='variable', order=[*'abcdefg'], ci=None)
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.barplot of long form dataframe]

Leave out `ci=None` if you do want error bars indicating a confidence interval.